# babel not converting files in sibling directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

my directory structure

```
components

+------ Input

          +-------- input.js


project

+-------.babelrc

+------- test.js

+------- testSetup.js
```

runner is mocha

---

problem is that i cant do `npm install` in components folder

my project is build using webpack and it can transpile input.js from `components` folder

but while running the tests i am not using webpack so babel cant transpile files in `components` directory.

my testSetup also contains this line

`require('babel-register')({
  resolveModuleSource: require('babel-resolver')('../node_modules')
});`

how can i babelify components in sibling directory from where the tests are being run .

Comment: Which testing library you use?

Comment: Mocha +enzyme+expect

Comment: Follow this https://x-team.com/blog/setting-up-javascript-testing-tools-for-es6/

Comment: thanks will have a look